# md5_file is that "safe" comparison i php

Tags: php, document-management, md5-file

I am about to build a simple document system in php. I would like to know if "md5_file()" is "safe" comparison for all filetypes.

I don't know all filetypes in the system. But I need to be able to compare all types.

Is there any alternatives?

Comment: All the function does is read a file and create an `md5` hash of its contents. It would be similar to you doing `md5 /path/to/file` on the command line. It won't execute any files, nor will it write.

Comment: "Safe" in what respect exactly?

Comment: With "safe" I am thinking i my application. If i am opening a file and make changes. What are the possibility that the md5 output will match the md5 from the old file.

Comment: Could you please mark an answer if it helped you in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions like md5_file(), sha_file() it does not matter what the actual content (or filetype) of the file is.

Answer (score 0):

sha1_file is an arguably "safer" calculation, but will also be slower.